# Looking up values between 2 pandas and if found do a calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have two dataframes one which is selection criteria and another which is results.  I need to look up the results to see if they match the selections and if so perform a calculation , I believe I have maybe used the wrong approach and while its getting me close to the answer I need the 2nd row should have a result of 16.0 but is showing 0.0 , PS hoping I have formatted correctly with code and then blockquotes for the results?  Cheers

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Sel = {'ID':[123,123,123,123,123],
        'M': [2,2,2,2,2],
        'R': [1,1,3,4,5],
        'S': [10,10,1,2,3],
       'BT': ['W','P','W','W','W'],
        'A': [10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0]
       
       }

df_sel = pd.DataFrame(Sel, columns = ['ID','M', 'R', 'S','BT','A'])

print (df_sel)
```

> ```
>     ID  M  R   S BT     A
> 0  123  2  1  10  W  10.0
> 1  123  2  1  10  P  10.0
> 2  123  2  3   1  W  10.0
> 3  123  2  4   2  W  10.0
> 4  123  2  5   3  W  10.0
> ```

```
Res = {#'ID':[123,123,123,123,123],
        'M': [2,2,2,2,2],
        'R': [1,3,1,4,5],
        'S': [10,10,10,7,6],
       'BT': ['W','P','P','W','W'],
        'A': [3.6,1.6,1.5,5.6,6.0]
       }

df_res = pd.DataFrame(Res, columns = ['M', 'R', 'S', 'BT','A'])

print (df_res)
```

> ```
>    M  R   S BT    A
> 0  2  1  10  W  3.6
> 1  2  3  10  P  1.6
> 2  2  1  10  P  1.5
> 3  2  4   7  W  5.6
> 4  2  5   6  W  6.0
> ```

```
# create a list of our conditions
conditions = [
    (df_sel['M'] == df_res['M']) & (df_sel['R'] == df_res['R']) & (df_sel['BT'] == df_res['BT']) & (df_sel['S'] == df_res['S']),
    (df_sel['M'] == df_res['M']) & (df_sel['R'] == df_res['R']) & (df_sel['BT'] == df_res['BT']) & (df_sel['S'] != df_res['S'])
    ]

# create a list of the values we want to assign for each condition
values = [df_sel['A']*df_res['A'],0.0]

# create a new column and use np.select to assign values to it using our lists as arguments
df_sel['result'] = np.select(conditions, values)

# display updated DataFrame
df_sel.head()
```

> ```
>      ID   M   R   S   BT  A   result
> 0 123 2   1   10  W   10.0    36.0
> 1 123 2   1   10  P   10.0    0.0
> 2 123 2   3   1   W   10.0    0.0
> 3 123 2   4   2   W   10.0    0.0
> 4 123 2   5   3   W   10.0    0.0
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left join with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by all columns, so for not matched get misisng values, which are replaced by `0` in [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) method, [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for use and drop column `A_`:

```
df = df_sel.merge(df_res, on=['M','R','BT','S'], how='left', suffixes=('','_'))

df['result'] = df['A'].mul(df.pop('A_'), fill_value=0)

print (df)
    ID  M  R   S BT     A  result
0  123  2  1  10  W  10.0    36.0
1  123  2  1  10  P  10.0    15.0
2  123  2  3   1  W  10.0     0.0
3  123  2  4   2  W  10.0     0.0
4  123  2  5   3  W  10.0     0.0
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing, really dumb question but how does the code you provided know what the calculation is to get the result ... its totally right but I just cant understand how it knows?

Comment: @RobPorter - Here is used instead `(df_sel['M'] == df_res['M']) & (df_sel['R'] == df_res['R']) & (df_sel['BT'] == df_res['BT']) & (df_sel['S'] == df_res['S']),` left join, so added new column only if match. else misisng value. So then multiple wit repalce misisng value by `0`

Comment: oh I think I get it so 'A'.mul is that multiplying it against A_ is that doing the multiplying?

Comment: @RobPorter - exactly. I use `mul` because possible replace `NaN` by `0`. another solution should be `df['result'] = df['A'] * df.pop('A_').fillna(0)`